# Impact of Economic Crisis on Supermarkets And Chemists?

Tags: microeconomics, financial-economics

In the undergoing Greek financial crisis, I’ve heard more than once that the three prime sufferers in any economic crisis are the 'bankers', 'supermarkets 'and 'chemists'. I do understand why the bankers could have trying times in a situation like this.

However, how does a recession like this impact supermarkets and chemists?

The only thing I can think of is it being a result of a hyper-inflation scare. If you could put it to me in the context of Greece's current situation, it'll help me understand it a lot better. So, for instance, how can dropping the Euro cause prices to rise?